# Do we need to prompt user regarding auto renewable subscription expire?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, auto-renewing

I have implemented Auto renewable subscription for In-App purchase.

At time of login I am verifying the reciept But what should be that next step if I am getting response as code-21006 that states subscription has been expire.

Do I need to prompt user regarding "Do you want to renew now" or it renews automatically though it sends 21006 code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Auto renewable** as it's name is auto and as long as your user is clear that he purchased an **Auto renewable** subscription you don't have to inform or ask every time. I looked at apple docs and there is no mention that you have to.

Don'f forget that the user will get a receipt from iTunes when the subscription will renew.

**BUT**
After all I think this is a good service to inform (not to ask) your user that the subscription has been renewed. As a customer I would appreciate that.

Comment: How will we able to know that auto-renew has been done as it returns code 0(zero) in success.Do we need to check for latest_receipt send by itunes at time of verification of receipt